# How to use awk to print line by line the result for an other program?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file.txt like :

```
AAAAAA
AAAAAB
AAAAAC
AAAAAD
...
```

And I want to use one line at the time for an other program. My script is using awk and its almost done but still doesn't work. Anyone can help please? Thanks!

```
while read file.txt

line=`awk '{ print $0 ; next}' ../file.txt`

echo 'for aa in "$line": cmd._alt(string.lower(aa)) ; save $line.pdb' > script.pdb

do

pymol script.pdb

done
```

The script should read each line of the file.txt individually to use the line in the 'for aa in "$line": cmd._alt(string.lower(aa)) ; save $line.pdb' script for pymol.

So the expected output should be a folder containing every files :

AAAAAA.pdb AAAAAB.pdb AAAAAC.pdb

Comment: What are you trying to do with input data shown?

Comment: This looping doesn't make much sense. Please provide more context

Comment: I think ..... is this what you want to do ? `sed 's/.*/for aa in "&": cmd._alt(string.lower(aa)) ; save &.pdb/g' file.txt`

Comment: It's hard to spot the problem with no program output, but try just killing the `next` statement from your awk script.

Comment: Every line is a sequence from a protein that I want to make generate via pymol with the pymol's command : for aa in "&": cmd._alt(string.lower(aa)) ; save &.pdb which will generate a pdb file for each individually.

Comment: The : sed 's/.*/for aa in "&": cmd._alt(string.lower(aa)) ; save &.pdb/g' ../file.txt is what I want but I can't make it save every line in an individual file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "for aa in \"$line\": cmd._alt(string.lower(aa)) ; save $line.pdb" > script.pdb
    pymol script.pdb
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks it's almost this! I'm trying this : `while read -r line

do
    echo "for aa in \"$line\": cmd._alt(string.lower(aa)) ; save $line.pdb" > script.py ; exit

    pymol script.py

done < ../file.txt` but Pymol get error and when I copy paste the line in pymol command it works... I don't know why

Comment: Ok now the script works, it was an error of .py to .pml but I can't make pymol close automatically between each line even with the quit pymol's command? `while read -r line

do
    echo "for aa in \"$line\": cmd._alt(string.lower(aa)) ; save $line.pdb" > script.pml ; quit

    pymol script.pml

done < ../file.txt`

Comment: Ok I got it ! `while read -r line do echo "for aa in \"$line\": cmd._alt(string.lower(aa)) ; save $line.pdb ; quit" > script.pml  pymol script.pml done < ../file.txt` Thanks everyone !!

Comment: I'm wondering if is it possible to make this command save the line where is it to start there if I stop the process ?

Comment: The script is running for a while now and it's slowing down. The file.txt is 47 000 000 lines. Is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: I've never worked with `pymol` .... I don't know if it support multithread or cluster

Comment: I know that pymol is using multithread cpu to render images but for structures I'm not sure and my CPU is only working at 25% maximum.  My point was more like is it possible to use awk or sed instead of "while read -r line" because it looks like it slows down a lot after only 15 000 lines.

Comment: The computer was still only used at 25% and memory at 3% after 32 765 files but the process has stopped saying the device doesn't have enough space. I'm doing it on a 64gb usb key. The pdb folder output is only 218.8 mg and there is 60gb free remaining on the usbkey.

Comment: Is it possible that the while read is creating a temp file which is growing in size overtime ?

Comment: Ok I've found out to accelerate the process. Creating a file containing all command lines with `sed 's/.*/for aa in "&": cmd._alt(string.lower(aa)) ; save &.pdb/g' file.txt` then make pymol open and creating every pdb with each lines. The problem is, that after 32 765 files it has stopped again due to disk space missing. Is it possible that is the maximum of files that can be created for 1 bash script?